# Controlling representation of datetime64[ns] in Pandas plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Say I have a dataframe and I do a boxplot:

```
df.boxplot(column='value', by='date')
```

where `date` is a column of dtype `datetime64[ns]`. When I run the above plot, the x-axis shows tick labels as follows:

```
2014-02-24 00:00:00
```

which are very wordy. I would like to just show something like `2014-02-24` (or even better, have the ability to control how dates are formatted (e.g. "Month-Day")

Is there any way to do this in Pandas?

For reference, I am using:

- matplotlib: `1.3.1`
- pandas: `0.13.1`
- numpy: `1.8.1`

and here are my dates:

```
In <88>: df['date'].head()
Out<88>: 
0   2014-02-24
1   2014-02-24
2   2014-02-24
3   2014-02-24
4   2014-02-24
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `ax` object (from `ax = plt.add_subplot(1,1,1)` or `ax = plt.gca()` for example) then you can use a [`DateFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) object as in the below code to set whatever string format you want.

The string options are those given by [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdate

df.boxplot(...)

ax = plt.gca() # Gets the current axes

# String giving your date format as "MM-DD" e.g. "04-29"
date_fmt = '%m-%d'

date_formatter = mdate.DateFormatter(date_fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)

fig.autofmt_xdate() # Sets your dates slightly diagonal to fit better.
```

Comment: Thanks. I am having trouble getting this to work. The auto-rotation works great, but the dates are still formatted as `2014-02-24 00:00:00`.. Hmm. And I made sure to call `boxplot` with the axes returned by `add_subplot` and everything

Comment: Also, it is not listening to other changes I want to make to the axes (e.g. `ax.set_title("Foo")`)

Comment: Although it does listen to figure changes.

Comment: Thanks. Also, even if I use `plt.gca()`, the `%m-%d` string does not print the Month and Day correctly (`2014-02-24` is shown as `01-01`). And if I include the year `%m-%d-%y` I get `01-01-87` (?)

Comment: Are you sure that your data is in the correct format? I've created an example `DataFrame` with `float` in one column and `datetime64[ns]` in the other and I produce the correct dates (see [here](http://pastebin.com/qXVH19N3))

Comment: I updated the OP to show `head` of the date columns. This is odd.

Comment: What version of numpy/pandas/matplotlib are you using? I'm using 1.8.0/0.13.1/1.3.1 respectively.

Comment: I updated the OP with version info. I am using a more recent version of numpy than you, but everything else is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can just create a new column of the strings values you want:

```
df['date1']=df.date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m-%y'))
ax=df.boxplot(column='value', by='date1')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks although I get: `numpy.datetime64` object has no attribute `strftime`

Comment: That is surprising. Can you add a line of `df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df.date)` and see if that helps. I suspect the problem originated in the way that you construct the dataframe and the `dtypes` of it.